# Making all PowerShell script variables explicitly Typed

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm new to PowerShell scripting and am looking to create ps1 scripts that I can used as cmdlets.  My background is in using strongly typed variables, but I'm struggling to find how (or if) it is possible to ensure that all user variables in a script are explicitly typed.  Some languages only allow explicitly typed variables. VBA allows the directive "Option Explicit" and I was hoping to find some way to achieve the same in any PSH scripts I create.
I've done a lot of searching (google, stackoverflow etc.) but not found anything.  If there is no way to force all variable definitions to be explicitly typed, I'll have to write a cmdlet to parse my scripts to find any implicitly typed variables ... but hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that in PowerShell. Closest you can get is to use [Set-StrictMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-7) which will, among other things, prohibit use of uninitialized variables.

But if you want to parse the scripts, maybe don't write your own solution. Use [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) module. It has a lot of built-in rules, unfortunately none for checking explicit types. But you can define your own rules, and maybe someone already created the one you're looking for and posted it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, both suggestions help greatly.